# Can calculation over rows can be simplified?

Tags: sql

I have a table something like this:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | var_1 | 1200 |
| 2 | var_2 | 300 |
| 3 | var_3 | 575 |
| 4 | var_4 | 20 |
| 5 | var_5 |  |

If I have formula for example,
`var_5 = (var_1 * var_4) - var_3 / var_2`
I have to create variables for every row one-by-one like this, and then I can do calculation and updating rows.

```
declare @var_1 int = (select value from table where id = 1)
declare @var_2 int = (select value from table where id = 2)
declare @var_3 int = (select value from table where id = 3)
declare @var_4 int = (select value from table where id = 4)

update table set value = [formula...] where id = 5
```

Now imagine I have a lot of variables (rows) involved in one calculation, or even I have to calculate many more. It would be a tedious work for me. Is there any solution to make it simple?

Comment: Either you have a seriously bad schema design, or a relational database is not the tool for this job. It's impossible to say from what you've posted here.

Comment: It looks like you need to pivot your data but it's not clear and it appears you may have over-simplified or abstracted too much.

Comment: Can you post the actual thing that you want to achive because what you are showing in example can be achive in while loop or you have problem with schema